# Proving that $a=2$ and $n$ is a prime given $p$ is a prime in $p= a^n - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a$ and $n$ be integers greater than $1$.

Suppose that $a^n - 1$ is prime. Show that $a = 2$ and that $n$ is prime.

---

First of all let   $$p =  a^n - 1$$

Since both $a$ and $n$ are integers greater than one then
$$p \ne 2$$

Thus $p$ is an odd prime

Rearanging: $$a^n = p + 1$$

Thus $a^n$ is an even integer, and then $a$ is and even integer.

Taking $\log_2$ of both sides:
$$ n\log_2(a) = \log_2(p+1) $$
and
$$n = \frac{\log_2(p+1)}{\log_2(a)}$$

Since n is an integer then 
$$\log_2(a) = 1$$ and $$a=2$$

I managed to get thus far, but when it comes to proving n is a prime I don't seem to know how to approach it.

Comment: How do you get $n = \frac{\log_{2}(p+1)}{\log_{2}(a)}\implies\log_2(a)=1$?

Comment: good point actually. it's not occured to me.

Comment: But it sure implies that $$a=2^k$$ and $$p+1=2^r$$ where $$r>k$$

Comment: $a^n-1$ is divisible by $a-1.$ Thus if $a\neq 2,$ $a^n-1$ can't be prime.

Comment: Similarly, $a^{pq}-1$ is divisible by $a^{p}-1$ and $a^{q}-1,$ so $n$ can't be composite.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$x^k-y^k=(x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+\cdots+y^{k-1}).$$
And you may want to use the formula for $x=a^t$ and $y=b^t$ for some integer $t$ to prove that $n$ is prime.